# Why can I add item to my list but not reallocate it?

Tags: c#

This might be a very noob question but I cannot fully understand why am I able to add items to my list and why can't I set it to null ?

```
public class Test
{
    public List<string> Source { get; set; }
    public Test()
    { this.Source = new[] { "Hey", "hO" }.ToList(); }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Test test = new Test();
        ModifyList(test.Source);
        //Why here test.Source.Count() == 3 ? Why isn't it null ?
    }

    private static void ModifyList(List<string> list)
    {
        list.Add("Three");
        list = null;
    }
}
```

Why after the call ModifyList, test.Source.Count() == 3 ? Why isn't it null ?

I would have expected the list to be either NULL or remain unchanged with two elements.

Can someone explain to me what is happening?
Thank you very much!

Comment: You're passing `list` parameter to the method and put it to null inside the method body this not affect `test.Source`. To affect `test.Source` you have to pass it by ref `ModifyList(ref List<string> list)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this method,

```
private static void ModifyList(List<string> list)
```

the `list` parameter is a reference that is passed by-value. You are adding to the referenced List, that is a normal operation. Then you set the by-valye copy to `null`. But the original reference (`test.Source`) remains unchanged.

In all your code, there is only 1 instance of `List<string>` but there are multiple references pointing to it at different times.

Comment: Thanks, that was the answer i was looking for "You are adding to the referenced List, that is a normal operation"

Answer (score 4):

This is a C# behavior. You are setting `list` to point to `null`, not the original list.

You should use the `ref` keyword to allow you to modify the original variable.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Test test = new Test();
        ModifyList(ref test.Source);
        //Why here test.Source.Count() == 3 ? Why isn't it null ?
    }

    private static void ModifyList(ref List<string> list)
    {
        list.Add("Three");
        list = null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

By executing `list = null;` you assign a new value to the local identifier `list`. You don't change (remove) the object that was stored in it previously.